# LocalStorage per page rather than (sub)domain?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

localStorage is per domain/sub-domain, but I need to store and retrieve values per page.

Does anyone have an expression that removes the domain, bookmarks and query-string from the location? I can then use encodeURIComponent and prepend each localStorage-key with this value.

In which case, I also need the 'reverse' to this expression in order to retrieve values just for the current page. EDITED I don't think I need a 'reverse' function - it would be the same expression.

If I have the two expression above, would you use this (stripped) location as a single key-entry, and stringify all the values I need for the page within it? This might be preferable as I can just check the location once to discover if it has any corrresponding localStorage.

Comment: Is location.pathname what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a function that generates a key for me, based on the page name (gotten from window.location) and appended with what the key *would have been*, then I store the data in localstorage.

```
function findPageName() {
    var path = window.location.pathname,
        s = path.split('/'),
        l = s.length,
        k = path.length,
        aux = 0;

    if (s[l - 1]) {
        return s[l - 1];
    } else if (l) { // l will always be a min of 2 (try '/'.split('/') )
        return s[l - 2];
    } else if (k == 0) {
        return '/'; //you likely want to replace this with another value
    } else {
        return s[1];
    }
}

function getKey(key) {
    return getPageName() + key;
}
```

Comment: This answers my question, thank you. Although, I'll use the pathname directly (I want the sub-folders as well), and just encode it as part of the key.

Comment: No problem. What you may want to do is replace the `'/'` in the pathname so that it doesn't negatively impact your stringification (it shouldn't, it's just a character), and then put an underscore between your page name and the key in the second function.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Yes, it did occur to me to replace the '/'. What I might do is store the page as one localStorage key, with a dummy value, and prepend the key-values with this page. This way, i can check if the page exists (as a key) before looping through all the other key values. Andy.

Comment: That sounds like an excellent turn of events for your efforts :D

Comment: It will be when I get there :) Stuck on an earlier issue at the moment though.. I'm using an index from getElementsByTagName('*') to store a comment (a textarea) and then attempting to re-insert the comment at the same position later (using bookmarklets). But the index number appears to change. I shall plough on :). Andy. It might be Google Ads, etc., modifying the page content.

Comment: Yeah, don't do that. Use a "Andy generated" ID rather than one from `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Can't do that - I use a bookmarklet to insert a comment, storing the comment and its 'position' in localStorage. When I revisit the page I want to re-instate the comment in its original position. Adding an id to the original comment won't help as it will disappear on re-load.

Comment: The three bookmarklets are here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewgsw/NxMgn/) if you're interested :) There's one to create a comment for selected text/word, one to save the comments, and one to re-display them. Quite interesting, but not quite there yet!

Comment: @codeisir did you really improve the answer by adding more spaces?